# CakePHP : Joining table with max value

Tags: cakephp, join, cakephp-2.2

Sorry im new in cakePHP. i use cakePHP 2.2. I have two table, Books and Transactions.

**Table : Books**

```
id
title
author
```

**Table : Transactions**

```
id
book_id
status
borrow_date
```

In table transaction list all transaction of the book.

My question, how to get status of max transaction id?

I try use this

```
options['joins'] = array(
            array(
                'table' => 'transactions',
                'alias' => 'Transaction',
                'type' => 'RIGHT OUTER',
                'fields' => array('MAX(Transaction.id)', '*'),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Catalogue.id = Transaction.catalogue_id',
                    //'Transaction.user_id' => $userId
                ),
                'order' => array('Transaction.id' => 'desc'),
            )
        );
        $this->set('Book', $this->Book->find('all',$options));
```

at view:

```
$Book['Transaction']['status'];
```

But it shows an error:

> Notice (8): Undefined index: Transaction [APP\View\Catalogues\user_katalog.ctp, line 32]

Answer (score 0):

You are doing find(all) so you have a list of books

```
var_dump($Book);
```

you will see

```
array(
   0 => array(
       'Transaction' => ...
   ),
   1 => array(
       'Transaction' => ...
   )
   .....
);
```

not

```
array(
   'Transaction' => ...
);
```

Either loop through `$Book` or use `find('first', ...)` if you want one.

Comment: can u give me some example?

Comment: <pre>

    foreach ($Book as $b):
    
        echo $b['Transaction']['status'];
    
    endforeach;

</pre> 

I use this, then show error 
<pre>

    Notice (8): Undefined index: Transaction [APP\View\Book\list.ctp, line 32] 

</pre>

Answer (score 0):

**dogmatic69** is right. Here's an example:
since you've used this in controller:

```
$this->set('Book', $this->Book->find('all',$options));
```

you should use this in view:

```
foreach( $Book as $b ) {
      echo $b['Transaction']['status'];
}
```

Comment: <pre><?php foreach ($Book as $B): ?>
          <tr>
              <td><?php echo $b['Book']['title']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $b['Book']['author']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $b['Transaction']['status']; ?></td>
          </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?></pre>
I use this, then show error
Notice (8): Undefined index: Transaction [APP\View\Catalogues\user_katalog.ctp, line 32]

Comment: i use as above statement you wrote

Comment: I don't know if you still need advice but here's what you've done wrong:I don't know if you still need advice but here's what you've done wrong:
By "<?php foreach ($Book as $B): ?>", you're extracting $Book as $B but you're printing "<?php echo $b['Book']['title']; ?>". It should be "<?php echo $B['Book']['title']; ?>". Notice that $b should be $B.